# Configuring network settings manually in Qubes OS

Tags: networking, configuration, qubes

I'm trying to setup [Qubes OS](http://qubes-os.org/) on my desktop but struggling to get the network/internet working.

This is the configuration i want to setup -

```
ip - 192.168.1.2
Subnet - 255.255.255.0
Gateway - 192.168.1.1
DNS - 8.8.8.8
interface - eth0
```

i tried following with limited success -

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0  
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

also edited /etc/resolv.conf to added dns entry.

Now when i check ifconfig - 
I get my ip & netmask configured and when i check routes i get 2 routes displayed with 192.168.1.1 as default.

But i still cannot surf or even ping domains (eg. www.google.com).

Qubes has various security domains called AppVm's. So i guess we could/might need to setup a network config for each VM. Its all a little new to me (+ its documented sparsely) so any help appreciated!

Comment: Since the network setup of Qubes OS is one of its defining characteristics (I guess), I suppose this can't be answered by someone not knowing it in detail. How about consulting [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/qubes-devel) if [the wiki](http://wiki.qubes-os.org/trac/wiki/UserDoc) doesn't help?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use NetworkManager system tray. Right-click on it, select edit connection, if the IPv4 tab, select manual and put your network settings in here.

Comment: How do you get to the NetworkManager? Is that the icon with two computers at the bottom right? If so while in dom0 I only have the option of clicking on 'VPN Connections' the two 'Ethernet Network' buttons are grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the ipaddress using following format

Here 192.168.1.1 is my Router (gateway)

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    dns-nameserver 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

you have to edit the resolv.conf for accessing the internet using and for permanent resolve you need to edit the base file too

```
vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

Append the below resovle

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Edit the base file

```
vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Append the below resovle

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me with qubes, have used all the releases since the first, is to let qubes acquire an ip address from my workstation/router's dhcp server.  This seems to have to be 10.137.1.x - per my experience.

In other words, set up my dhcp server/router to allocate an ip address in the range 10.137.1.1 to 10.137.1.255, or some subset of that range.

When I fit in with qubes this way, it works like a charm, (from qubes) pinging google.com to my heart's content, updating/upgrading, viewing web pages, etc. - hth